# pyspark 3.0 KMeansModel within set sum of squared errors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to calculate the within set sum of squared errors by computeCost method but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'KMeansModel' object has no attribute 'computeCost'
```

I guess it is deprecated but I couldn't find a way to do it. I always get computeCost in my searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is resolved by using `model.summary.trainingCost` instead of `model.computeCost`